# How to get loggedin user id after user logs out in spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have created a following LogoutSuccessHandlerImpl

```
public class LogoutSuccessHandlerImpl extends SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler {

    private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        final Long currentUserRoleId = SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserRoleId();

        request.getSession().invalidate();
        SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

        request.setAttribute("isLoggedOut", "true");
        if(currentUserRoleId == UserRole.ADMIN.getId()){
            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, Constants.ADMIN_LOGIN_URL);
        } else {
            redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, Constants.APPLICANT_LOGIN_URL);
        }
    }
}
```

and below is my security config.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/accessDenied")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager)
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/application/register**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/adminLogin**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/checkLogin**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/checkLogin")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/dashboard")
                .failureHandler(new LoginFailureHandlerImpl())
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(new LogoutSuccessHandlerImpl())
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .headers()
                .frameOptions()
                .disable()
            .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1);
    }
```

Below is my SecurityUtils.

```
public static SecurityUser getCurrentUser() {
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        Authentication authentication = securityContext.getAuthentication();
        if (authentication != null) {
            if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof SecurityUser) {
                return (SecurityUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("User not found!");
    }

    public static Long getCurrentUserRoleId() {
        return SecurityUtils.getCurrentUser().getRoleId();
    }
```

and the error i get is

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: User not found!
    at com.portal.core.user.security.SecurityUtils.getCurrentUser(SecurityUtils.java:34)
    at com.portal.core.user.security.SecurityUtils.getCurrentUserRoleId(SecurityUtils.java:38)
    at com.portal.core.user.security.LogoutSuccessHandlerImpl.onLogoutSuccess(LogoutSuccessHandlerImpl.java:22)
```

Comment: @W-S If if (authentication != null)  is not satisfied. Just before user is logged out, Authentication should not be null. So exception should not be there. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`LogoutSuccessHandler` will be called after all the `LogoutHandler`s are finished executing. This means by the Your code in `LogoutSuccessHandlerImpl.onLogoutSuccess` is called when there will be nothing in `SecurityContextHolder`. This is because a `SecurityContextLogoutHandler` will be registered by default. The following line in your `LogoutSuccessHandlerImpl` has no effect as it is already done by `SecurityContextLogoutHandler`.

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

You can do the following.

1. Store the User Id and Role Id in the Http Session
2. Configure your logout to have `logout().invalidateHttpSession(false)`
3. Modify your `LogoutSuccessHandlerImpl.onLogoutSuccess` to get the User Id and Role Id from HttpSession instead of `SecurityContextHolder`

Answer (score 0):

`authentication` is always `null`, because `LogoutSuccessHandler` is called after a successful logout, see [`LogoutSuccessHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutSuccessHandler.html):

> Strategy that is called after a successful logout by the LogoutFilter, to handle redirection or forwarding to the appropriate destination.

You could implement a custom [`LogoutHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutHandler.html) to get user's role id before a successful logout, see [`LogoutHandler#logout`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutHandler.html#logout-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-org.springframework.security.core.Authentication-):

> **Parameters:**
>
> request - the HTTP request
>   response - the HTTP response
>   authentication - the current principal details